# The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or a server failure

Tags: content-editor, publishing, paas

when I am going to publish any single item from the Sitecore content tree I am getting the below error:

[image]

Application is migrated from `Sitecore version 9.0.2 to 10.2` and deployed on `Azure PAAS` environment. It's perfectly working fine in the developer workstation.

Can anyone please guide me, on what can be the reason, or am I missing some configuration on Azure?

Comment: I'd say your first Step is to look at the Sitecore logs. Either in App Insights on on the CM or Publishing Instance (depending on your Setup). You should see some info there to give you and idea of what is up.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamSeabridge, Unfortunately, there is no error in the logs.

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat Have you checked the publishing log? The main log file may not have the publishing information.

Comment: I would check the App Service in Azure and see what the CPU & Memory usages are like, but also check out the following admin page within your Sitecore instance to see what jobs a running `https://<hostname>/sitecore/admin/Jobs.aspx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this below attribute HTML tag missing in the `web.config`.

```
    <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```

I have updated my `web.config` with below attributes in respective tags:

```
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="512000"
                 executionTimeout="600" enableKernelOutputCache="false"
                 relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="false" requestValidationMode="4.0"
                 enableVersionHeader="false"
                 requestValidationType="Sitecore.Web.RequestValidators.SitecoreBackendRequestValidator, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```